# Экспорт таблицы из Excel в Word файл

Tags: c#

Столкнулся с трудностью, нужно экспортировать таблицу из excel файла в word.
Может кто подсказать, как это реализовать? (может быть у кого нибудь уже есть готовый вариант)

Answer (score 2):

Есть библиотеки для работы с Microsoft Office:

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel и Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
Добавь их в проект через NuGet и будет тебе счастье.

Реализация:

```
        using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

        Word.Application wdapp = new Word.Application();
        Word.Document wddoc = wdapp.Documents.Add();
        string xlSheetPath = @"D:\\New\\1.xlsx"; \\ **Путь к файлу Excel**
        string ext = xlSheetPath.Substring(xlSheetPath.LastIndexOf("."),
            xlSheetPath.Length - xlSheetPath.LastIndexOf("."));
        int xlVersion = (xlSheetPath.Substring(xlSheetPath.LastIndexOf("."),
            xlSheetPath.Length - xlSheetPath.LastIndexOf(".")) == ".xls") ? 8 : 12;
        wdapp.Selection.Fields.Add(wdapp.Selection.Range, Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldLink,
            "Excel.Sheet." + xlVersion.ToString() + " " + xlSheetPath + " Лист1!R1C1:R13C5 \\a \\f 5 \\h", true); \\ **Выбор нужного диапазона для переноса**
        wdapp.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Уже добавлял. Вообще пробовал по вот этому методу. Но так и не понял, как его реализовать. http://www.cyberforum.ru/windows-forms/thread809561.html

Comment: "Приложению Word не удалось создать связи с указанным объектом. Вставьте объект непосредственно в файл без использования связи." А в самом word документе написано "Ошибка! Ошибка связи." Диапазон брал вот такой (A1G1:A290G290 я же правильно его указал? Мне нужно от А1 до G290.)

Comment: Furianec Переведите в R1C1 формат, в коде указано, что интексаторы ячеек только в таком формате

Comment: В общем так и не получилось сделать как у вас. Не понимаю, что с этой строчкой не так. wdapp.Selection.Fields.Add(wdapp.Selection.Range, Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldLink,
            "Excel.Sheet." + xlVersion.ToString() + " " + xlSheetPath + " Лист1!R1C1:R13C5 \\a \\f 5 \\h", true); \\ **Выбор нужного диапазона для переноса**

Comment: @Furianec На пальцах: R1C1 - Row 1, Column 1 (это A1) : R13C5 - Row 13, Column 5 (это E13), все что в пределах этого диапазона - экспортируется в другой файл.

Comment: А можно еще вопрос, а как мне задать размер шрифта и его тип. Пробую вот так, но что-то не получается.             worksheet.Range["A1", "G6"].Font.Size = 12;  worksheet.Range["A1", "G6"].Font.Name = "Times New Roman";

Comment: @Furianec За выбор параметров переноса данных ячеек отвечает эта часть:  **\\a \\f 5 \\h"**. Советую почитать про "wdapp.Selection.Range, Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldLink" на https://msdn.microsoft.com, в частности про WdFieldType.

Comment: Попробовал еще раз ваш метод, но ничего не выходит. Все та же ошибка(ошибка связи. в самой студии ничего не вылезает, вылезает именно в офисе самом.) По поводу "wdapp.Selection.Range, Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldLink" так ничего и не понял. Разве можно тремя переменными регулировать переносом? Как мне это поможет продублировать все строки в столбцах на другом листе, если хотя бы в 1 строке текст не влез на страницу и переехал на другую.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал вот так.

```
   Word.Application wdapp = new Word.Application();
        Word.Document wddoc = wdapp.Documents.Add();
        string xlSheetPath = textBox1.Text;
        string ext = xlSheetPath.Substring(xlSheetPath.LastIndexOf("."),
            xlSheetPath.Length - xlSheetPath.LastIndexOf("."));
        int xlVersion = (xlSheetPath.Substring(xlSheetPath.LastIndexOf("."),
            xlSheetPath.Length - xlSheetPath.LastIndexOf(".")) == ".xls") ? 
 8 : 12;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application xlApp = new 
  Excel.Application();
        xlApp.Visible = true;
        Excel.Workbook workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(xlSheetPath);
        Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Sheets[1];

        Word._Application wdApp = new Word.Application();
        wdApp.Visible = true;
        Word.Document document = wdApp.Documents.Add();
        document.PageSetup.Orientation = 
    Word.WdOrientation.wdOrientLandscape;

        worksheet.Range["A1", "G6"].Copy();
        document.Range().PasteSpecial();

        workbook.Close();
        xlApp.Quit();
```

Но теперь не понимаю, как сделать, что бы текст с других столбцов переезжал на другую страницу, если хотя бы в 1 столбце текст не влезал на страницу. Может кто подсказать, как это реализовать?